# Кто может начертить блок схему?

Tags: python

```
stroka=input("\n Введите строку: ")
print("\n", stroka)
tmp=""
n=len(stroka)
for i in range(0, n):
      tmp=stroka[i]+tmp
print("\n Строка наоборот: ", tmp)
```

Comment: работа со строками. нужно убедиться в том что введенное слово является полиндромом

Comment: нужно просто сделать проверку является ли слово полиндромом и все?

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле полиндром на python проверяется легко:

```
stroka = input("\n Введите строку: ")
if (stroka == stroka[::-1]):
      print("Строка полиндром")
else:
      print("Строка не полиндром")
```

[image: Блок-схема]